# How do I make a D3.js donut chart (aster plot) animate on page load with transition

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, data-visualization, transition

I am new to d3.js and have been exploring how to visually make data more attractive since I have a background in visual communication.
I was wondering if any of you experts could give me a hand on solving a challenge I am facing with some animations.

I wanted to create an animate the graphs on the load of the page maybe with an elastic effect.
Here is what I have as an example for a bar chart with the transition I am imagining.

```js
var bardata = [];

for (var i=0; i < 100; i++) {
 bardata.push(Math.round(Math.random()*30))
}

var height = 400,
    width = 600,
    barWidth = 50,
    barOffset = 5;

var tempColor;

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
    .style('position', 'absolute')
    .style('padding', '0 10px')
    .style('background', 'white')
    .style('opacity', 0)

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, bardata.length*.33, bardata.length*.66, bardata.length])
    .range(['#FFB832','#C61C6F', 'red', 'blue'])

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
    .range([0, height]);

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(0, bardata.length))
    .rangeBands([0, width])


var myChart = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
       .attr('width', width)
       .attr('height', height)
       .selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
       .enter().append('rect')
           .style('fill', function(d, i) {
            return color(i);
           })
           .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
           .attr('height', 0)
           .attr('x', function(d,i) {
               return xScale(i);
           })
           .attr('y', height - 0)
       .on('mouseover', function(d) {


        tooltip.transition()
         .style('opacity', .9)

        tooltip.html(d)
         .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
         .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 35) + 'px')

        tempColor = this.style.fill;
        d3.select(this)
         .style('opacity', .5)
         .style('fill', 'yellow')
       })
       .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        
       tooltip.transition()
         .style('opacity', 0)

        d3.select(this)
         .style('opacity', 1)
         .style('fill', tempColor)
       });


myChart.transition()
  .attr('height', function(d) {

               return yScale(d);
           })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
               return height - yScale(d);
           })
        .delay(function(d,i) {
         return i * 15;
        })
        .ease('elastic')
        .duration(1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Bar chart</h2>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Now I wanted to make a same transition for a donut chart, or better said an aster plot like this one below. Animation on load of page from center to outwards.
http://bl.ocks.org/bbest/2de0e25d4840c68f2db1

I have been trying again and again the last few weeks but since I am still new, I had to come here for some help.

Hope to here some expert advice on this!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (animating aster plot slices from inner radius to their final radius) and managed to get it working, merging stuff from the "Aster Plot" example and the "Arc Tween" example and adapting it to my data.
I don't know if it's the best solution (d3 noob also) but at least, it's working.

Basically, when drawing the arc, instead of calling directly the arc function, I put an `attrTween` calling an `arcTween` function that will call the arc function with interpolation.

So

```
arcs.append('path')
  (other attr like filling, stroke, etc)
  .attr('d',arc)
```

becomes

```
arcs.append("path")
// (other attr like filling, stroke, etc)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attrTween('d', arcTween(innerRadius));
```

and the function arcTween is

```
function arcTween(newH) {
  return function(d) {
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(newH, d.data.hauteur);
    return function(t) {
      d.data.hauteur = interpolate(t);
      return arc(d);
    }
  }
}
```

`d.data.hauteur` being the `outerRadius` you want to get for that pie slice.